# Sourcetree Clone Stuck

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-clone

I am using `SourceTree` GUI for cloning a repository from bitbucket.

I have done all the settings in correct manner. But my clone gets stuck like this for hours without any message.

What can be wrong?

[image: It is stuck here]

Comment: SourceTree used to be a good piece of software until Atlassian started "improving" it several years ago :-( What happens if you run the `git clone` command in a terminal? You can copy it from the SourceTree window and you don't need the myriad of `-c` options and their parameters. `git clone --branch ...` (and everything after `--branch`) is enough.

Comment: Happened to me a couple of times. I cloned from command line with the same result. Finally it was a connection issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issue with SourceTree while cloning a GitHub repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20718193/issue-with-sourcetree-while-cloning-a-github-repository)