# How can I delete all SSH keys from my Mac

Tags: ssh, terminal

So I am starting bootcamp at the end of this month and I have pre course work until then. I have previously set up keys but I want to know how to delete all of them because, well I would just like to know. Basically when I command

ls -al ~/.ssh

I would like it to respond

total 0

Currently It's responding

total 8

Mostly the reason I'm asking is in the tutorial the instructor is saying he deleted all of them to start clean for the purpose of the video.

Here is the link to said video. https://youtu.be/5I1rlq7qkps

Thank you!

Comment: ``rm -rf ~/.ssh/``

Answer (score 19):

You can do `rm -rf ~/.ssh/*` to remove everything in your `.ssh` folder.

Answer (score 6):

Also you could run `ssh-add -D` first. It makes me feel good, feels safer than only removing whole directory right off the bat